# Turn off pluralization of class names in cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp, bootstrapping

How to Turn off pluralization altogether in cakephp2.2

This is the source code of my page:

```
<form action="/scores/exam2014s/aview" id="exam2014AviewForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

In the above code suffix - 's' in 'exam2014s' is appearing automatically, which i dont want kindly help how to avoide the pluralization of the above.

In the bootstrap.php, I have used the following code `enter code here`to turnoff pluralization:

```
Inflector::rules(
'plural', 
array(
    'rules' => array('/^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$/i' => '\1'), 
    'irregular' => array(), 
    'uninflected' => array()
)
```

);

With the above code in bootstrap I could not fix the problem.

Code in my index.ctp is below:

```
echo $this->Form->create('exam2014', array('action' => 'aview'));
echo $this->Form->label('Page.name','Name: ',null);
echo $this->Form->input('qr_code');
echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Thanks in advance.

Sai Krishna

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. Not that 'exam2014' is an invalid scope / model name here.

Comment: DO you know why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simply the following code?

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'exam2014', 
    array(
       'url' => array('controller' => 'exam2014', 'action' => 'aview')
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Cake2.x the form posts to itself by default.
So simply do:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Exam2014');
```